# Serialize Map<String, BigDecimal> values as Shape.STRING

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I know it's possible to control the shape of a `BigDecimal` being serialized by Jackson by using something like `@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING)`.

What I can't figure out is how to enable that on a `BigDecimal` in a `Map` value, without having to configure the `ObjectMapper` globally.

```
mapper.configOverride(BigDecimal.class)
        .setFormat(JsonFormat.Value.forShape(JsonFormat.Shape.STRING));
```

I'm looking for something, I imagine an annotation or two, to ensure the property is always serialized as a string, regardless of `ObjectMapper` configuration.

```
// what @Json... annotations here
private Map<String, BigDecimal> foo = ImmutableMap.of(
    "USD", new BigDecimal("1.50"),
    "GBP", new BigDecimal("6.66")
);

// will produce this
{
    "USD": "1.50",
    "GBP": "6.66"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems it's not possible to use that annotation for map value.

But in this particular case you can put the annotation on the map itself:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
private Map<String, BigDecimal> foo = ImmutableMap.of(
    "USD", new BigDecimal("1.50"),
    "GBP", new BigDecimal("6.66")
);
```

It will produce what you expect.

(Jackson 2.9.5+)